# How to make a JSON data entry whose value is sum of other two entries?

Tags: javascript

i have some example data in a javascript file. I am passings it value in a html page which is showing them after some calculation. Here is the data :

```
{
    "name" : "Provider Name",
    "breakfast_price" : "1.95",
    "lunch_price" : "19.90",
    "dinner_price" : "29.95",
    "all" : "50.00"
}
```

now what i want is that the vale of "all" is the sum of previous 3 float values.
And yes i want the sum in string. How can i achieve this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to show us your code attempts to solve your own issue and others help fix your code when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: JSON is a string so to update that string you have to create, get, or create the string (possibly from a JavaScript object like you have) No jQuery here so I remove that tag. In addition "previous 3 float values" - those are strings you need to parse, not numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "Provider Name",
  "breakfast_price": "1.95",
  "lunch_price": "19.90",
  "dinner_price": "29.95",
  "all": "50.00"
};

const { breakfast_price, lunch_price, dinner_price } = obj;
obj["all"] = ((+breakfast_price) + (+lunch_price) + (+dinner_price)).toFixed(2);


console.log(obj);
```

Comment: For consistent decimal length consider using `String#toFixed()`

Comment: It returns a string so `toString()` is redundant